# How do I change my default "test app" in Actions On Google?

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to learn how to use the Google Assitant API. I had some luck when playing around with my first test app, "app1". Now, I want to build a new test app.

At this point, I have set up a number of *Agents* in Dialogflow. Lets call them "app1", "app2" and "app3". I am experimenting in app3 and adding *Intents*. When I click "see how it works in Google Assistant" and I say "talk to my test app" it constantly launches in to the app1 agent. I'm not sure how I get it to launch in to the app3 agent instead.

So, my question is, **when using *Dialogflow* and *Actions On Google*, where do I set what "my test app" refers to?** Can I say something else to get it to launch app3 specifically?

Answer (score 2):

Disable the apps you do not want to test from the simulator by clicking on the Testing on device button. (See image below)

[image]

Consider giving your apps different names and pronunciations.

Answer (score 0):

Dialogflow agents are linked to individual Google Projects. This means a single Dialogflow agent can only be linked to a single Actions Console project (i.e. one app for Assistant). When testing a given project, it will use the linked Dialogflow agent.

See the [FAQ](https://dialogflow.com/docs/concepts/google-projects-faq) for more.